# Binomial/combinatorics summation proof question

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Given $\sum_{k=0}^{2r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k} = (-1)^r\binom{n}{r}$ for $0≤r≤\frac12n$

How do I show that $\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k} = \frac12(-1)^r\binom{n}{r}[1+\binom{n}{r}]$ for $0≤r≤\frac12n$

For context, the first statement is derived from considering the coefficient of $x^{2r}$ in the statement $(1-x)^n(1+x)^n=(1-x^2)^n$ where $2r≤n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use symmetry: we split the sum into two parts and then we change the index in the second one by letting $j=2r-k$,
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^{2r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}&\binom{n}{2r-k}=\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}+\sum_{k=r+1}^{2r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}+\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (-1)^{2r-j} \binom{n}{2r-j}\binom{n}{j}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}+\sum_{j=0}^{r} (-1)^{j} \binom{n}{2r-j}\binom{n}{j}- (-1)^{r}\binom{n}{r}^2\\
&=2\sum_{k=0}^{r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}- (-1)^{r}\binom{n}{r}^2.
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how exactly the second line follows from the first. Are you using $\binom{n}{r}=\binom{n}{n-r}$ to get the result? If it's not too much to ask, could you show an extra line of working between the two?

Comment: @Quippy I edited my answer with an extra line. Is it better now?

Comment: I'm so sorry I meant I don't get how $\sum_{k=r+1}^{2r} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k}\binom{n}{2r-k}=$$\sum_{j=0}^{r-1} (-1)^{2r-j} \binom{n}{2r-j}\binom{n}{j}$

Comment: @Quippy Change index of summation: let $j=2r-k$ then $k=r+1,\dots, 2r$ becomes  $j=0,\dots, r-1$.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help :)

Comment: (+1) I'd written an answer, thinking it was simpler, but then upon looking closer, I realized that it was essentially the same.